# Bash scripting call to AWK

Tags: bash, awk

I'm having difficulty getting the awk command inside a bash script to work.  The script follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
fpga-test -1 -a $1 > tmp.file && awk  \'\/Read\/ {print \$2}\' tmp.file
```

When I run the command I get the following error.

```
# my_script 14
awk: cmd. line:1: Unexpected token
```

The intermediate file (tmp.file) looks like this, and I want only the second tokenized string.

```
Read 32769 or -32767 (0x8001) @ 0x0e
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem with your escaping. Also, there is no need for a temporary file in this case.

```
#!/bin/bash
fpga-test -1 -a $1 | awk  '/Read/ {print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Turing:~ vince$ cat ex.txt 
Read 32769 or -32767 (0x8001) @ 0x0e
Read 32769 or -32767 (0x8001) @ 0x0e
Read 32769 or -32767 (0x8001) @ 0x0e

Turing:~ vince$ awk '/Read/ {print $2}' ex.txt 
32769
32769
32769
```

Is that what you want?